# How to declare a function with val in Scala that takes no Input

Tags: scala

We know that in scala, you can declare a function like a variable, using val. For example, if I want to declare a function that returns the square of a number, I can write it like this.

```
val square: Long => Long = x => x * x
```

But how do I declare a function with this style, if it takes no input. For example, I wanted to declare a function which gives time in secs, so I declared it like this.

```
val secs: Unit => Long = x => System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
```

Is there a more elegant way to declare such functions, as the `x =>` here is kind of useless. Note that I don't want to declare it using `def`.

Comment: You can short the definition a little bit with: `val secs = () => System.currentTimeMillis / 1000`.

Comment: And to clarify, the type of Suárez' comment and Jeffrey's answer is `() => Long`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to define `secs` as follows:

```
val secs = () => System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
```

Call it with `secs()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use functional interfaces like this:

```
object Seconds extends (Unit => Long) {
  def apply(): Long = System.currentTimeMillis / 1000
}
```

You can then call it like:

```
Seconds()
```